# Failed to mount /sysroot - zfs on lvm on luks with detached header

Tags: systemd, boot, luks, zfs

I tried to install a fresh system. With encrypted zfs and a detached header and boot on usb.
But I can't boot, because the mount of /sysroot is failing.
[image: systems boot log]

I tried changing the kernel parameters and different hooks. I can not enter the emergency shell because root seems to be locked, although a password is set for root. So I have only access through a live iso.

journalctl in the chroot replies with no journal.

This is my setup:

```
sda                         
└─luksCont              crypt
  ├─systemVG-rootLV     lvm   
   |   └─zfs pool                /mnt
  └─systemVG-swapLV     lvm   

sdc (USB)                   
├─sdc1             /mnt/efi
└─sdc2             /mnt/boot
                      └─luksheader, keyfile
```

*/etc/mkinitcpio.conf* (what I changed)

```
FILES=(/boot/header.img /boot/key.img)

HOOKS=(base systemd autodetect modconf keyboard sd-vconsole block mycustomencrypthook lvm2 zfs filesystems)
```

*/etc/initcpio/install/mycustomhook*

```
#!/bin/bash

build() {

    local mod
    add_module dm-crypt

    if [[ $CRYPTO_MODULES ]]; then

        for mod in $CRYPTO_MODULES; do
            add_module "$mod"
        done

    else

    add_all_modules '/crypto/'

fi

add_binary "cryptsetup"
add_binary "dmsetup"
add_file "/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/10-dm.rules"
add_file "/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/13-dm-disk.rules"
add_file "/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/95-dm-notify.rules"
add_file "/usr/lib/initcpio/udev/11-dm-initramfs.rules" "/usr/lib/udev/rules.d/11-dm-initramfs.rules"
add_runscript

}
```

*/etc/initcpio/hooks/mycustomhook*

```
#!/usr/bin/ash

run_hook() {

modprobe -a -q dm-crypt >/dev/null 2>&1
modprobe loop

[ "${quiet}" = "y" ] && CSQUIET=">/dev/null"

echo 'Waiting for USB:'
echo ' /efi '
i=1
sp="/-\|"
echo -n ' '

while [ ! -L '/dev/disk/by-uuid/3EF6-1EDA' ]; do

    printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
    sleep 1
done
printf "\bfound!"

echo ' /boot '
i=1
echo -n ' '

while [ ! -L '/dev/disk/by-uuid/1667-253D' ]; do

    printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
    sleep 1
done
printf "\bfound!"

#mkdir -p /mnt
#mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/1667-253D /mnt

#cryptsetup open /mnt/key.img lukskey
cryptsetup open /boot/key.img luks-key
cryptsetup open /dev/disk/by-id/ata-SAMSUNG... --header=/boot/header.img --key-file=/dev/mapper/luks-key enc

cryptsetup close luks-key
}
```

*/efi/loader/loader.conf*

```
default archlinux
timeout 3
console-mode max
editor 1
random-seed-mode with-system-token
```

*/boot/loader/entries/archlinux.conf*

```
title Arch Linux
linux /vmlinuz-5.10-x86_64
initrd /intel-ucode.img 
initrd /initramfs-5.10-x86_64.img
options root=zfs:AUTO 
#options root=zfs:rpool/ROOT/arch
#options root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/arch
#options zfs=rpool/ROOT/arch
```

Zfs mounts

```
zfs get mountpoint

        rpool                                mountpoint  /mnt                           local
        rpool/ROOT                           mountpoint  none                           local
        rpool/ROOT/arch                      mountpoint  /mnt                           local
        rpool/ROOT/opt                       mountpoint  /mnt/opt                       local
        rpool/ROOT/usr                       mountpoint  /mnt/usr                       local
        rpool/ROOT/usr/local                 mountpoint  /mnt/usr/local                 inherited from rpool/ROOT/usr
        rpool/ROOT/var                       mountpoint  /mnt/var                       local
        rpool/ROOT/var/lib                   mountpoint  /mnt/var/lib                   inherited from rpool/ROOT/var
        rpool/ROOT/var/lib/systemd           mountpoint  /mnt/var/lib/systemd           inherited from rpool/ROOT/var
        rpool/ROOT/var/lib/systemd/coredump  mountpoint  /mnt/var/lib/systemd/coredump  inherited from rpool/ROOT/var
        rpool/ROOT/var/log                   mountpoint  /mnt/var/log                   inherited from rpool/ROOT/var
        rpool/ROOT/var/log/journal           mountpoint  /mnt/var/log/journal           inherited from rpool/ROOT/var
        rpool/home                           mountpoint  /mnt/home                      inherited from rpool
        rpool/home/maksim                    mountpoint  /mnt/home/maksim               inherited from rpool
        rpool/home/root                      mountpoint  /mnt/root                      local
```

I’m a bit confuesed why

```
zfs mount
```

shows different output for me from within the chroot

```
zfs mount (in chroot)
rpool/ROOT/arch /
```

(in live system)

```
zfs mount (in live system)

rpool/ROOT/opt                  /mnt/opt
rpool/home/root                 /mnt/root
rpool/ROOT/var/log              /mnt/var/log
rpool/home                      /mnt/home
rpool/ROOT/var/lib/systemd/coredump  /mnt/var/lib/systemd/coredump
rpool/ROOT/usr/local            /mnt/usr/local
rpool/home/maksim               /mnt/home/maksim
rpool/ROOT/var/log/journal      /mnt/var/log/journal
rpool/ROOT/arch                 /mnt
```

Answer (score 0):

I just spend the last couple hours working through the same error but with a single disk set up. Perhaps this will help.

Try running a LIVE USB/CD on the machine and mount the EPS partition. In there check out the `loader/entries/arch.conf` file. What I found is that I had a setting like `root=PARTUUID=xxxxxxxx...`. What I had to do was change it to `root=/dev/mapper/<partition label>`. This it worked as expected. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of the kernel parameter root. Since I'm using ZFS, I set it to my zfs root dataset root=zfs:rpool/ROOT/arch. The zfs option is defined here https://github.com/openzfs/zfs/blob/adc851d9f83579f31903007e3ce0af24faceb21b/contrib/dracut/90zfs/parse-zfs.sh.in#L35